# Segue from editActionsForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitableviewrowaction

I'm making a little banking type app, for instructional purposes.

All transactions are stored as Core Data entities, fetched and sorted using Magical Record helper methods. The transactions are displayed in a `UITableView`, fed by a `fetchedObjects` array.

I want to be able to use `editActionsForRowAtIndexPath` like so:

[image]

The first action segues to another `uiviewController`, the second and third to a `UIPopoverPresentationController`. The fourth button deletes the transaction.

### **EDIT**

Here's the code to create the buttons:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //Obviously, if this returns no, the edit option won't even populate
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //Nothing gets called here if you invoke `tableView:editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:` according to Apple docs so just leave this method blank
}

-(NSArray *)myArray:(UITableView *)tableView editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewRowAction *delete = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleDefault title:@"Delete" handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath)
                                    {
                                        // Delete code here
                                    }];

    UITableViewRowAction *changeAmt = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleDefault title:@"Amt" handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath)
                                       {
                                           // popover amount change code
                                       }];

    changeAmt.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.022 green:0.541 blue:0.001 alpha:1.00];


    UITableViewRowAction *changeAcct = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleDefault title:@"Acct" handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath)
                                        {
                                            // popover account change code
                                        }];

    changeAcct.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.000 green:0.492 blue:0.000 alpha:1.00];

    UITableViewRowAction *viewTrans = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleDefault title:@"View" handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath)
                                        {
                                            // Push to view
                                        }];
    viewTrans.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.002 green:0.342 blue:0.710 alpha:1.00];


    return @[delete, changeAmt,changeAcct,viewTrans]; //array with the buttons delete, changeAmt, changeAcct, viewTrans
}
```

**Here's my question:**

How do I tell which button to trigger which segue? I can't figure how to make the connections.

Here's a representative chunk of code from my `prepareForSegue`. One point of my confusion is indicated by the ??? in the argument for the `sourceRect`:

```
else if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"AmountPopSegue"])
{
    UIViewController *controller = segue.destinationViewController;
    controller.popoverPresentationController.delegate = self;
    controller.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 186);
    UIPopoverPresentationController *thisPPC = controller.popoverPresentationController;


    thisNavController = (UINavigationController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    AmountChangePopVC *acVC = (AmountChangePopVC *)thisNavController.topViewController;
    acVC.delegate = self;
    thisPPC.sourceRect = ???;
}
```

All insights appreciated. I'm writing in Objective C because I started this project before Swift became all the rage.

Comment: How did you achieve the multiple actions for a cell? A third party library or using the original method?

Comment: I used the UiTableView delegate methods canEditRowAtIndexPath and commitEditingStyle followed by editActionsForRowAtIndexPath. It's an easy implementation, that part of it at least.

Answer (score 0):

This method can help you. You'll know which button was tapped.

--Be careful. this method only work in iOS 8 or later.--

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSIndexPath *firstButtonIndexPath;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSIndexPath *secondButtonIndexPath;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSIndexPath *thirdButtonIndexPath;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSIndexPath *fourthButtonIndexPath;

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        if (self.firstButtonIndexPath) {
            NSLog(@"ViewButton :%ld", (long)self.firstButtonIndexPath.row);
        } else if (self.secondButtonIndexPath) {
            NSLog(@"Acct :%ld", (long)self.secondButtonIndexPath.row);
        } else if (self.thirdButtonIndexPath) {
            NSLog(@"Amt :%ld", (long)self.thirdButtonIndexPath.row);
        } else if (self.fourthButtonIndexPath) {
            NSLog(@"Delete :%ld", (long)self.fourthButtonIndexPath.row);
        }
    }
}

- (NSArray *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    self.firstButtonIndexPath = nil;
    self.secondButtonIndexPath = nil;
    self.thirdButtonIndexPath = nil;
    self.fourthButtonIndexPath = nil;

    UITableViewRowAction *viewAction = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleDefault title:@"View" handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath) {
        NSLog(@"View the row");
        self.firstButtonIndexPath = indexPath;
    }];
    viewAction.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    UITableViewRowAction *acctAction = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleDefault title:@"Acct" handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath) {
        NSLog(@"Acct the row");
        self.secondButtonIndexPath = indexPath;
    }];
    acctAction.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];

    UITableViewRowAction *amtAction = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleDefault title:@"Amt" handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath) {
        NSLog(@"Amt the row");
        self.thirdButtonIndexPath = indexPath;
    }];
    amtAction.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

    UITableViewRowAction *deleteAction = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleDefault title:@"Delete" handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath) {
        NSLog(@"Delete the row");
        self.fourthButtonIndexPath = indexPath;
    }];
    deleteAction.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    return @[deleteAction, amtAction, acctAction, viewAction];
}
```

Comment: I maybe should have mentioned that I've already got that method implemented. So is the idea to pluck the relevant button from the resulting array?

Comment: For some reason I only saw the bottom half of your code. I'll try this method asap and let you know if it works for me. Might be a day or so, as I had something else come up. Thanks!